# "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" Unreal 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I know this might be a question for gamedev but since Im having the problem in Visual studio Im putting it here.

first, here are 2 source code snippets

code chunk 1

```
#pragma once
#include "Components/SceneComponent.h"
#include "CanonLauncher.generated.h"


UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BLOCKASSAULT_API UCanonLauncher : public USceneComponent
 {
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
// Sets default values for this component's properties
UCanonLauncher();
std::vector<int> canon;


// Called when the game starts
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

// Called every frame
virtual void TickComponent( float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction ) override;
int canonTime = 120;
canonTime = canonTime - 1;



};
```

code chunk 2

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Components/SceneComponent.h"
#include "CanonLauncher.generated.h"


**UCLASS** ( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class BLOCKASSAULT_API UCanonLauncher : public USceneComponent
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
// Sets default values for this component's properties
UCanonLauncher();
std::vector<int> canon;


// Called when the game starts
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

// Called every frame
virtual void TickComponent( float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction ) override;
int canonTime = 120;
canonTime = canonTime - 1;



};
```

the first one throws no errors, but obviously my vector code wont work, nor will my variable manipulation for that matter. so I added the bit you see in bold. now the variable manipulations, flow controls, and vectors work but now the bit surrounded by double Asterisks ("**") throws the error

> this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

ADDENDUM 1:

Yeah, I know iostream and vector are creating a code collision with one of the UE4 headers, that bit seems obvious, I just don't know how to work around it

Comment: `#include "Runtime/CoreUObject/Public/UObject/Class.h"` [from here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/UClass/index.html#references)

Comment: ahhh wait that's for `UClass` not `UCLASS`

Comment: What is `canonTime = canonTime - 1;` doing in the middle of class definition???

Comment: @AnT I was declaring canon time then having it decrease by 1 every tick... this is c++ btw, as it says in the tags

Comment: @Carson: In C++ you cannot write code in the middle of class definition. Code is supposed to reside in functions. This, again, raises the question of what that `canonTime = canonTime - 1;` doing there and how do you expect this to cause it to "decrease by 1 every tick". Just get and read a book on the basics of C++ syntax.

Comment: @AnT I put a declaration inside a function, not the other way around, which is allowed in C++

Comment: @Carson: "Inside a function"? Where? In C++ language function body begins with a `{` and ends with a `}`. I don't see a single function body anywhere in the code you posted. Nothing is "inside a function" in your code.

Comment: @AnT how did I not notice that I forgot to bracket up.... wow... okay, so... OH! I get it now, you're brilliant. Thank you so much